# Ubuntu 12.04 Issue

Tags: boot

The installation completes and I restart the computer.  I enter my password and am taken to what I believe is supposed to be the desktop.  It is a blank, sort of mauve/orange colored screen with no icons nor menu bar(s).  The screen suddenly becomes black and I can see only my mouse pointer (I am able to move the pointer).
Then a window pops up containing the following error message:

```
      System Program Problem Detected
      Do you want to report the problem now?
      Cancel                 Report Problem
```

I click on "Report Problem," and wait.  Nothing happens.  The button itself appears to become smaller than the other button so I assume it "clicked."

Please help me.  Everything appears to have installed properly but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the "Ubuntu2d" session (pic from 11.10 attached but the option is the same).

[image]